# Gitlab-ci limit stages in template

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a `template.yml`

```
stages:
  - a
  - b
  - c
```

i have an `another.yml` in which I want to re-use and limit the number of available stages

```
include:
  - project: 'project'
    ref: project
    file: 'ci_templates/.template.yml'
```

I tried to add in `another.yml`

```
stages:
   - a
   - b
```

but it fails with `c job: chosen stage does not exist`

How to re-use in `another.yml` only `a` and `b` stages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could disable `c` stage like this

```
c:
  stage: c
  rules:
   - when: never
```

Answer (score 1):

you should add variables and some rules in your template.yml like:

```yaml
# template.yml

stages:
  - stage_1
  - stage_2
  - stage_3

variables:
  ENABLE_STAGE_1: "true"
  ENABLE_STAGE_2: "true"
  ENABLE_STAGE_3: "true"

stage1 job:
  stage: stage_1
  script:
    echo "stage1 job"
  rules:
    - if: $ENABLE_STAGE_1 != "true"
      when: never
    - when: always

stage2 job:
  stage: stage_2
  script:
    echo "stage2 job"
  rules:
    - if: $ENABLE_STAGE_2 != "true"
      when: never
    - when: always

stage3 job:
  stage: stage_3
  script:
    echo "stage3 job"
  rules:
    - if: $ENABLE_STAGE_3 != "true"
      when: never
    - when: always
```

when you don't run some stage you can override your variables, look like the .gitlab-ci.yml

```yaml
# .gitlab-ci.yml 

include:
  local: template.yml

variables:
  ENABLE_STAGE_3: "false"
```